# Using php to show a file on ftp server

Tags: php, file, ftp

I got a ftp server with a file called "file.txt".
On my website, i would like to show what this file contains using php.
what i got:

```
<?php
session_start();


$_SESSION["ftp_pass"] = $_POST["pass"];
$_SESSION["ftp_user"] = $_POST["user"];
$ftp_pass = $_POST["pass"];
$ftp_server = "ftp.guusvanwalstijn.nl";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 


// Error when wrong password/username/server offline
function error_while_connecting() {
echo "Error while connecting to the server";
echo "<br />Probably the password is wrong or the server is offline";
}

//log in
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    echo "succes";
} else {
    error_while_connecting();
    print("<br />Debug: " . $_POST["pass"] . "<br />");
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like that:

```
 <?php
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/text.txt"; //Path to your *.txt file 
$contents = file($file); 
$string = implode($contents); 

echo $string; 
?>
```

Comment: What i have done is:
function test()
{
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/file.txt"; //Path to your *.txt file 
$contents = file($file); 
$string = implode($contents); 

echo $string;
}

But what happends is that it tries to open a file called "file.txt" from my webhost, cause when creating file.txt in my webhost, it does show eveything inside this file

Comment: Ahh never mind i change $_SERVER to $ftp_server. Thank you so much